# Chef - Block not being executed even tho its notified?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

i've looked over this code a few times and i'm not sure why the extract_presta block isnt being triggered. I've confirmed the file i'm looking for isnt in the /var/www/html directory :c)

What i'm trying to achieve is to:

- download a file, unzip it, but only if a specific file doesn't exist
- Stop apache after downloading, unzip the file
- start apache

Could i ask for some advice please? thanks.
-nat

```
service "apache" do
  action :nothing
end

execute 'extract_presta' do
  command 'unzip /tmp/prestashop_1.7.4.2.zip'
  cwd '/var/www/html'
  not_if { File.exists?("/var/www/html/autoload.php") }
  action :nothing
  notifies :start, "service[apache]"
end

# Fetch the file. Maybe the file won't be fetched because of not_if or checksum.
# In that case apache won't be stopped or started, it will just keep running.
  remote_file "/tmp/prestashop_1.7.4.2.zip" do
  source "https://download.prestashop.com/download/releases/prestashop_1.7.4.2.zip"
  notifies :stop, "service[apache]", :immediately
  notifies :run, 'execute[extract_presta]', :immediately
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the download already exist? If so, then the `remote_file` resource would be marked up-to-date and wouldn't fire notifications.

Comment: Well - that was a learning curve :) thanks CodeRanger, yes the download existed.

It's not how i understood that function to work, but hey! when i deleted the download, magic happened and the rest executed.

thanks for the response, i appreciate it.